# Random number generator in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Hi how can you generate a random int between 0 and 10 in kotlin ? I tried `Random().nextInt()` and `val rnds = (0..10).random()` but i can't generate one. Thanks

Comment: Which Kotlin version? (0..10).random() works for >= 1.3

Comment: Please post code, otherwise we have no idea what the issue is. Also, what do you mean by 'you can't generate one'? Whats your code even doing then?

Comment: `val r = (0..10).random()` as given in the other post.

Answer (score 3):

To generate random number you can do as follow:

```
val randomNumber: Int = Random().nextInt(10) // here you can set your own bound value. This will give you random number from 0 to 10
```